# msys2 static libzmq won't link to dependencies in mingw cmake project

Tags: c++, cmake, linker, mingw, zeromq

Here is my project:

project structure:

```
test/
    CmakeList.txt
    main.cpp
    external/
        cppzmq/...
```

cppzmq from https://github.com/zeromq/cppzmq

Cmake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)



add_definitions(-DZMQ_STATIC)
link_libraries(wsock32 ws2_32 sodium)

option(CPPZMQ_BUILD_TESTS "" OFF)
add_subdirectory(external/cppzmq/)

add_executable(test main.cpp)

#note cppzmq-static should be an interface target
target_link_libraries(test PUBLIC cppzmq-static)
#if(MINGW)
target_link_libraries(test PUBLIC wsock32 ws2_32 libsodium.a)
#endif()
target_compile_definitions(test PRIVATE -DZMQ_STATIC)
```

Here is my main file (I don't expect it to do anything, I'm just trying to get it to fail on linking):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <zmq.hpp>
int main() {
    
    zmq::context_t context(1);


    zmq::socket_t req_socket(context, ZMQ_PAIR);
    req_socket.bind("tcp://foo");


    zmq::socket_t threads_sub(context, ZMQ_SUB);
    threads_sub.bind("tcp://bar");
    threads_sub.set(zmq::sockopt::subscribe, "a");
    threads_sub.set(zmq::sockopt::subscribe, "b");
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here is my Cmake output:

```
"path\cmake.exe" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles" path\test
-- Detected CPPZMQ Version - 4.8.0
-- CMake libzmq package not found, trying again with pkg-config (normal install of zeromq)
-- Found PkgConfig: path/pkg-config.exe (found version "1.7.3") 
-- Checking for module 'libzmq'
--   Found libzmq, version 4.3.3
-- cppzmq v4.8.0
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: path/test/cmake-build-debug

[Finished]
```

Here is my build output (note entire build output exceeds char limit, used ellipses to cut down on chars)

```
"path\cmake.exe" --build path\test\cmake-build-debug --target test -- -j 12
Scanning dependencies of target test
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/test.dir/main.cpp.obj
[100%] Linking CXX executable test.exe
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-zmq.o):(.text+0x1a49): undefined reference to `__imp_select'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-zmq.o):(.text+0x1cdd): undefined reference to `__WSAFDIsSet'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-zmq.o):(.text+0x1cf7): undefined reference to `__WSAFDIsSet'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-zmq.o):(.text+0x1d11): undefined reference to `__WSAFDIsSet'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-zmq.o):(.text+0x2031): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAGetLastError'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-socket_poller.o):(.text+0x3a0): undefined reference to `__WSAFDIsSet'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-socket_poller.o):(.text+0x3bb): undefined reference to `__WSAFDIsSet'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-socket_poller.o):(.text+0x3d3): undefined reference to `__WSAFDIsSet'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-socket_poller.o):(.text+0x43d): undefined reference to `__WSAFDIsSet'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-socket_poller.o):(.text+0x128d): undefined reference to `__imp_select'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-socket_poller.o):(.text+0x12bb): undefined reference to `__WSAFDIsSet'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-socket_poller.o):(.text+0x142b): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAGetLastError'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-err.o):(.text+0x4b6): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAGetLastError'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-err.o):(.text+0x603): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAGetLastError'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-ip.o):(.text+0x2f): undefined reference to `__imp_setsockopt'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-ip.o):(.text+0x5f): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAGetLastError'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-ip.o):(.text+0x14e): undefined reference to `__imp_WSASocketA'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-ip.o):(.text+0x182): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAGetLastError'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-ip.o):(.text+0x1dc): undefined reference to `__imp_ioctlsocket'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-ip.o):(.text+0x1ff): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAGetLastError'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-ip.o):(.text+0x28a): undefined reference to `__imp_setsockopt'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-ip.o):(.text+0x2af): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAGetLastError'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-ip.o):(.text+0x36f): undefined reference to `__imp_getnameinfo'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-ip.o):(.text+0x3c3): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAGetLastError'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-ip.o):(.text+0x473): undefined reference to `__imp_setsockopt'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-ip.o):(.text+0x497): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAGetLastError'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-ip.o):(.text+0x534): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAStartup'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-ip.o):(.text+0x62a): undefined reference to `__imp_WSACleanup'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-ip.o):(.text+0x64f): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAGetLastError'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-ip.o):(.text+0x7ad): undefined reference to `__imp_setsockopt'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-ip.o):(.text+0x7e5): undefined reference to `__imp_htonl'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-ip.o):(.text+0x7f1): undefined reference to `__imp_htons'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-ip.o):(.text+0x82d): undefined reference to `__imp_bind'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-ip.o):(.text+0x845): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAGetLastError'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-ip.o):(.text+0x84e): undefined reference to `__imp_closesocket'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-ip.o):(.text+0x8b5): undefined reference to `__imp_getsockname'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-ip.o):(.text+0x8cc): undefined reference to `__imp_listen'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-ip.o):(.text+0x8e8): undefined reference to `__imp_connect'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-ip.o):(.text+0x908): undefined reference to `__imp_accept'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-ip.o):(.text+0x95f): undefined reference to `__imp_recv'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-ip.o):(.text+0x990): undefined reference to `__imp_send'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-ip.o):(.text+0x9d1): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAGetLastError'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-ip.o):(.text+0xa5d): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAGetLastError'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-ip.o):(.text+0xae3): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAGetLastError'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-ip.o):(.text+0xb53): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAGetLastError'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-ip.o):(.text+0xbc3): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAGetLastError'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-ip.o):(.text+0xc33): more undefined references to `__imp_WSAGetLastError' follow
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-ip.o):(.text+0xe3c): undefined reference to `__imp_getsockopt'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-ip.o):(.text+0xe69): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAGetLastError'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-random.o):(.text+0xa5): undefined reference to `sodium_init'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-random.o):(.text+0xd1): undefined reference to `randombytes_close'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-select.o):(.text+0x70d): undefined reference to `__WSAFDIsSet'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-select.o):(.text+0x75e): undefined reference to `__WSAFDIsSet'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-select.o):(.text+0x7a6): undefined reference to `__WSAFDIsSet'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-select.o):(.text+0xd2d): undefined reference to `__imp_select'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-select.o):(.text+0xd7f): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAGetLastError'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-select.o):(.text+0xf11): undefined reference to `__imp_getsockopt'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-select.o):(.text+0xf33): undefined reference to `__imp_getsockname'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-select.o):(.text+0x118d): undefined reference to `__imp_WSACreateEvent'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-select.o):(.text+0x11ef): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAGetLastError'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-select.o):(.text+0x1263): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAGetLastError'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-select.o):(.text+0x12d3): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAGetLastError'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-select.o):(.text+0x1343): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAGetLastError'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-select.o):(.text+0x13bd): undefined reference to `__imp_WSACloseEvent'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-select.o):(.text+0x1417): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAGetLastError'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-select.o):(.text+0x1483): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAGetLastError'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-select.o):(.text+0x14f3): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAGetLastError'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-select.o):(.text+0x1563): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAGetLastError'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-select.o):(.text+0x1698): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAEventSelect'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-select.o):(.text+0x16ba): undefined reference to `__WSAFDIsSet'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-select.o):(.text+0x16ce): undefined reference to `__WSAFDIsSet'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-select.o):(.text+0x16e1): undefined reference to `__WSAFDIsSet'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-select.o):(.text+0x16f5): undefined reference to `__WSAFDIsSet'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-select.o):(.text+0x170d): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAEventSelect'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-select.o):(.text+0x1733): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAGetLastError'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-select.o):(.text+0x17d5): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAWaitForMultipleEvents'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-select.o):(.text+0x18a8): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAEventSelect'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-select.o):(.text+0x190a): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAGetLastError'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-select.o):(.text+0x1e13): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAGetLastError'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-select.o):(.text+0x1fb3): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAGetLastError'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-select.o):(.text+0x2153): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAGetLastError'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-select.o):(.text+0x22f3): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAGetLastError'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-select.o):(.text+0x2493): more undefined references to `__imp_WSAGetLastError' follow
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-signaler.o):(.text+0x8a): undefined reference to `__imp_setsockopt'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-signaler.o):(.text+0x9e): undefined reference to `__imp_closesocket'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-signaler.o):(.text+0xcd): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAGetLastError'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-signaler.o):(.text+0x133): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAGetLastError'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-signaler.o):(.text+0x1cb): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAGetLastError'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-signaler.o):(.text+0x24f): undefined reference to `__imp_send'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-signaler.o):(.text+0x29f): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAGetLastError'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-signaler.o):(.text+0x3d2): undefined reference to `__imp_select'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-signaler.o):(.text+0x42b): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAGetLastError'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-signaler.o):(.text+0x53c): undefined reference to `__imp_recv'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-signaler.o):(.text+0x57b): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAGetLastError'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-signaler.o):(.text+0x6ac): undefined reference to `__imp_recv'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-signaler.o):(.text+0x6e3): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAGetLastError'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-stream_listener_base.o):(.text+0x113): undefined reference to `__imp_closesocket'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-stream_listener_base.o):(.text+0x1ff): undefined reference to `__imp_closesocket'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-stream_listener_base.o):(.text+0x223): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAGetLastError'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-tcp.o):(.text+0x2d): undefined reference to `__imp_setsockopt'
```

...

```
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-udp_address.o):(.text+0x549): undefined reference to `if_nametoindex'
```

...

```
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-curve_client.o):(.text+0x44f): undefined reference to `crypto_box_keypair'
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-
```

...

```
path/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: path/msys2/mingw64/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-curve_client.o):(.text+0xfd8): undefined reference to `sodium_free'
```

...

```
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\test.dir\build.make:107: test.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:115: CMakeFiles/test.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:122: CMakeFiles/test.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:183: test] Error 2
```

I don't know what the deal is, it doesn't appear to be able to link to lib sodium, but I'm clearly adding it to the link libraries (twice!).  It also appears to be missing some wsock32 ws2_32 things, and again, I specify *those* in the link libraries (and again, twice!). What is going on here?  How do I get it to properly link to the things I'm directly telling it to link to?

Comment: You may use verbose build (e.g. by execute appropriate `make` utility with `VERBOSE=1` option) for see which **actual parameters** are passed to the linker.

Comment: Why don't you build without the testing (cmake flags `-DBUILD_TESTING:BOOL=OFF -DCPPZMQ_BUILD_TESTS:BOOL=OFF`) ? Symbol `sodium_free` is part of libsodium. Do you have that installed?